# mysql : Data too long for column on alter table modify column

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am changing a column from text to varchar column.

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID           | bigint(19)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| STATUS           | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PRIORITY         | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DESCRIPTION      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

when i execute the below query,

```
alter table StatInfo modify column DESCRIPTION varchar(255) NULL;
```

It says
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'DESCRIPTION' at row 7

It doesn't truncates the value in the column and alters the table why?. where as in older version it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you need to check the sql mode, if it strict then it will show this error

> When you change a data type using CHANGE or MODIFY, MySQL tries to
>   convert existing column values to the new type as well as possible.
>
> Warning This conversion may result in alteration of data. For example,
>   if you shorten a string column, values may be truncated. To prevent
>   the operation from succeeding if conversions to the new data type
>   would result in loss of data, enable strict SQL mode before using
>   ALTER TABLE (see Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to
1) Copy that table on a temporary table (through an insert-select)
2) Alter the original table
3) Restore the values in the original table using the same procedure described in 1)